# Find the basis for the following linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

The following linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is given:

$$U := \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4 | \ x_2 + x_3 - x_4 = 0, \ 4x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4 = 0 \}$$

I know what a linear subspace is and what a basis is. However, it is not clear to me how to solve the given problem. I solved the system of linear equations [here](https://matrixcalc.org/de/slu.html#solve-using-Gaussian-elimination%28%7B%7B0,1,1,-1,0%7D,%7B4,-1,1,1,0%7D%7D%29) but I don't know how to use the solution. I also tried googling and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you solved the system of linear equations and you got that $x_1=-\frac12x_3$ and that $x_2=-x_3+x_4$. Note that there are no restrictions on $x_3$ or $x_4$. So, take $x_3=1$ and $x_4=0$, thereby getting$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\left(-\frac12,-1,1,0\right).$$Now, take $x_3=0$ and $x_4=1$, thereby getting$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(0,1,0,1).$$So, you have your basis:$$\left\{\left(-\frac12,-1,1,0\right),(0,1,0,1)\right\}.$$